# Having key value separated on python with boto

Tags: python, dictionary, boto3

I am trying to get only the value from a dictionary in python>
I followed this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-how-to-loop-a-dictionary/) but I have a weird error telling me

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

But it is not a list it is a dictionary (I think...)

there is my code

```
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(
      Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['in-use']}]) 

for volume in volumes:
      print(volume.attachments)


for k, v in volume.attachments.items():
      print("Code : {0}, Value : {1}".format(k, v))
```

As a result of the first print it shows this :

```
[{u'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 14, 54, 27, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'InstanceId': 'i-xxxxxx', u'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxxx', u'State': 'attached', u'DeleteOnTermination': True, u'Device': '/dev/sda1'}]
```

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When the interpreter tells you a value is a list I would be inclined to believe that. Particulary since the printerd value begins with `[` and ends with `]`. If that's not a list, I am Guido van Rossum.

Comment: Also, you just happen to be operating on the last `volume` because that's what the preceding loop left in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the dictionary nested in a list. You have to iterate through the list to access all the `attachments` to that volume. Your approach only takes the last `volume` from the previous iteration, you should instead nest the *for-loops* to view all the volumes:

```
for volume in volumes:
     for attachment in volume.attachments:
         for k, v in attachment.items():
             print("Code : {0}, Value : {1}".format(k, v))
```

If each volume will ony have one attachment, then it is sufficient to index the *list of attachments* at index 0:

```
for volume in volumes:
    for k, v in volume.attachments[0].items():
        #                          ^
        print("Code : {0}, Value : {1}".format(k, v))
```

Comment: Thanks Moses, perfect. I do understand how it works now.

Comment: @HouariSonnyTADJER You may consider accepting if you found the answer useful :)

Comment: sorry I did not know this. 1st time asking a question. done :)